# How do I deploy a react js app to a S3 bucket in a bundled fashion?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, amazon-s3

I am hosting a react production app in s3, which works great.

However, I can see all my source code (components, redux ...) showing in chrome browser [(see this chrome screen shot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8n6h.png)

Is there a way for me to serve only the bundled javascript file?

Comment: Have You tried *anything*?

Comment: You need to host only the compiled css and js you dont need to host the dev files

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options which you could possibly do wrong

1. Wrong files uploaded - you've uploaded dev files and not bundled to single file with some package bundler e.g Webpack in production mode
2. Wrong compilation - You have compiled your production mode with dev flags or even with sourcemaps as referred here https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/ this allows Chrome to see full structure and filenames even if you upload only 1 bundle.js, it's some sort of mapping to be understandable by browser for development purposes